# How to call phone number from abroad that starts with a star?

Tags: phone-networks

I want to call a phone number in Bulgaria, but currently I am in other country and the phone number is ***6161**. Is there a way to call this number from abroad?

Comment: That is not a phone number but rather some service code from your mobile provider. Did you try it out if it works nonetheless?

Comment: Does your phone keypad not have a star button?  Or is the problem something else?

Comment: @Sebastian: In Germany, there was some discussion about using * numbers as some kind of vanity number, to be implemented at the provider level. Anybody calling from outside would have had to use a different number.

Comment: Related question: [How can I call a 4-digit French phone number from the US?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12137/164)

Comment: @Sebastian It is actually a phone number. It can also be dialled from fixed network lines.

Comment: This number can be dialed only from Bulgarian mobile network. You have to be in Bulgaria and have a Bulgarian phone mobile provider to dial this number, but my problem is that I have a Bulgarian mobile card, but I can't call this number outside Bulgaria. It turns out there is other number which is 0700 1 6161. I was thinking there is some kind of converter, but I guess I am wrong.

Comment: Does the business that uses this number provide an alternative for calling from abroad? I don't think you'll be able to dial a [Premium-rate number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premium-rate_telephone_number) from outside Bulgaria either. Typically, the number should start with a 00 359 or +359

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza, yes you are right. The phone number I end up calling was +359 700 1 6161, but this is actually other phone number, I was thinking there is a way to convert this number into an actual calling number. For example if I want to call my operator from Bulgaria I have to call *88, but from abroad I have to call +359 888 123, so I guess there isn't a way to convert this number to an international number which you can call.